# What does "Edit" mean in the review section of 'Suggested edit'?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I got an edit suggestion approved recently. I usually check the review results to see if something could have been done better and I found that one of the result was "Edit" (instead of the usual Approve or Rejected).

[image]

I checked the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), but I couldn't figure out what it means.

Was something added to the suggested edit by the user? Or is "Edit" an indication for further editing?

Comment: See in the dupe under "Sometimes the Community user approves or rejects my edit. What does that mean?"